# Why can't I install/start minidlna?

Tags: services

Since this week start, I can no more start minidlna. The main change being I had an electric shutdown of my Raspberry.

When I try to start the service using `service minidlna start`, the service doesn't start and I get messages like

```
Failed to start LSB: Start minidlna at boot time.
-- Subject: L'unité (unit) minidlna.service a échoué
```

Being a Windows user, I reinstalled minidlna, which lead to another set of errors like

```
nov. 18 19:01:07 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start minidlna at boot time...
-- Subject: L'unité (unit) minidlna.service a commencé à démarrer
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- L'unité (unit) minidlna.service a commencé à démarrer.
nov. 18 19:05:56 raspberrypi sshd[3211]: Received disconnect from 123.244.9.80: 11:  [preauth]
nov. 18 19:06:07 raspberrypi systemd[1]: minidlna.service start operation timed out. Terminating.
nov. 18 19:06:07 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Start minidlna at boot time.
-- Subject: L'unité (unit) minidlna.service a échoué
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- L'unité (unit) minidlna.service a échoué, avec le résultat failed.
nov. 18 19:06:07 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Unit minidlna.service entered failed state.
nov. 18 19:06:10 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Reloading.
```

I guess minidlna installs correctly, but can't start ...
Do anybody have an idea about why minidlna can't start ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it's not at all a problem with minidlna, but rather a FS problem.
Indeed, the files I use are stored on an NAS, which seems to have disk issues. As a consequence, I'm unable to perform `ls` on the folder used as minidlna source (it hangs exactly in the same way minidlna does).